# How do I say "Don't forget to forgive" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like say in latin "Don't forget to forgive". It would be like a declarative/recommendation statement.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9):

There's an already nice construction in Latin: *memento mori*, which more literally means "remember to die", though it really means something like "don't forget that you're mortal."

Substituting one word for another we get: **memento ignoscere**, "Remember to forgive."

Comment: It should be spelled "memento ignoscere." It looks like an innocent typo intruded.

Comment: @user1071303 Yep, thanks. Late night typos.